# Sharepoint 2013 _vti_bin/listdata.svc REST API information

Tags: rest, api

How to modify information that is comming from `http://ourintranet/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` ? 
How to check where that info is stored?
Something like OData Connection or Information Design Tools is needed?

Comment: I connected ussing tableau ODATA, but I see just field names, not values itself.
I need to acces actuall data that i get dislpayed..

Answer (score -1):

You can use  Excel Service to retrieve the data using the given query.
Please refer this [url](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2015/07/28/excel-services-consuming-a-sharepoint-list-using-the-listdata-svc/)

Comment: are you using windows authenication or do you have separate credentials for this SP site?

Comment: 'I went to Data > Connections > Properties > Definition tab > Authentication Settings > Use a stored account > (enter a SSS ID you have created).'
In Secure Store Service application page in central administration I see two application ID but they are not related to my extracted list

'NOTE: the “Set Credentials” account for this SSS ID needs to have access to the SharePoint List.'
What is this Set credentials account?

Btw I need to update data on Sharepoint after retrieving and modifying it. Is it possible?

Comment: I am using Active Directory authentication

Comment: Open Excel > Data tab > From Other Sources  > From Odata Feed > http://sp/_vti_bin/listdata.svc (also check "**use this name and password**" and give your username and password as shown in the screenshot of the url I shared)